# Create array having into account in input has value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to build a 5x5 grid with random alphabetical characters, unless if a text input has a value. If that input has a value, the two cells in the grid will be filled with that value and the rest of the grid will be filled with random alphabetical characters. If the input has no value, the grid will be filled as usual.

```
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

const getRandomLetterRow = (size) =>
  Array.from({ length: size }, () => {
    return alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
  });

const generateGrid = (size = 5) => {
  return Array.from({ length: size }, () => {
    return getRandomLetterRow(size);
  });
};

    function App(){
             const [customLetter, setCustomLetter] = useState();
             const [grid, setGrid] = useState(generateGrid());

             console.log(grid);

             return(
                  <div>
                      <input
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="Type"
                           onChange={(e) => setCustomLetter(e.target.value)}
                      />
                  </div>
              )
    }
```

I got to the part where the grid is filled with random alphabetical characters, but I can't find out how to fill just two cells with the input value. If the input has value, I need to be able to create the array where two values are the input value and the rest will be random alphabetical characters, if not, it will created as it is right now.

Comment: What do you mean by "the two cells"? what two cells exactly?

Comment: I'm building a 5x5 grid. Two of those 25 cells.

Comment: which two? the first two? last two? what?

Answer (score 0):

Some changes are :-

```
function App() {
   const [grid, setGrid] = useState(()=>generateGrid());
   return (
        <div className="App">
        <input
           type="text"
           placeholder="Type"
           onChange={(e) => setGrid((prev)=>{
                   return prev.map((value,index)=>{
                       if (index === 0){
                        return  [e.target.value,e.target.value,...value.slice(2)]
                       }
                       return value
               })
             })}
      />
  
</div>
);
}
```